# How to use the cached Array's length in CoffeeScript's "for in" loop?

Tags: for-loop, coffeescript

[The following CoffeeScript code:](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3afor%20a%20in%20arr%0A%20%20do_something_with%20arr.length)

```
for a in arr
  do_something_with arr.length
```

is compiled to:

```
var a, _i, _len;

for (_i = 0, _len = arr.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  a = arr[_i];
  do_something_with(arr.length); // I want to use '_len' here
}
```

Is that possible to use the cached value of `arr.length` rather than calculating it in every iteration?

Comment: You could calculate the length outside the loop (as @francpaul) suggested below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a defined array and not a ranged array, then you could actually use _len in the block:

```
for a in arr
  _len == arr.length
```

however, this relies on the CS internals, which could change in a new version.
It also does not work for every array.

```
arr = [0..10]
for a in arr
  #this works
  console.log _len
```

but:

```
for a in [0..10]
  #this doesn't work
  console.log _len
```

I think if you want to used a cached version of the array length, it is better to do that explicitly in your code and not depend on the internal variable names of CS.

rather do:

```
arrLength = arr.length
for a in arr
   doSomethingWith arrLength
```

Comment: The last approach is probably the simplest. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Consider?

```
for i in [0...len = arr.length]
  a = arr[i]
  do_something_with len
```